# Wrapping a Row of Texts with Colored Rounded Box

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Based on the code below, how does one wrap around a row of texts in a container? *(as shown in the image)*. And also, how to make the container slightly rounded as shown in the image?

When I wrap it in a container, why does it takes up the full width of the app from left to right, which is not what I am trying to achieve.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Expanded(
              child: PageView(
                controller: _pageController,
                onPageChanged: (page) {
                  setState(() {
                    currentIndex = page;
                  });
                },
                children: [
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 0, left: 220, right: 30, bottom: 0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 7,
                                child: Text(
                                  '187,177.33',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 4,
                                child: Text(
                                  '82',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `decoration` on Container. Also reduce the padding,

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
    child: Row(
```

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        child: Expanded(
          child: PageView(
            // controller: _pageController,
            onPageChanged: (page) {
              setState(() {
                // currentIndex = page;
              });
            },
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 7,
                              child: Text(
                                '187,177.33',
                                style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 4,
                              child: Text(
                                '82',
                                style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

More information about [`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Answer (score 0):

`Container` has property which called `decoration`, It would does the job for you, Try this:

```
Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                          padding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                '187,177.33',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 10),
                              Text(
                                '82',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
```

[image]

Comment: This works but would work best if it were to wrap the container in a padding so it doesn't get scratched the full width. Thanks for your help!

Comment: instead of wrap it in padding set width for it, something like this: width :MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6; in this way you get same aspect in many screen size.